# Datatable and Datagridview cell calculation

Tags: vb.net

This my initial code,

```
Private Sub Create_vTable()
    Dim i,j As Integer
    Dim q, PV, YP, MW, id As Double

    q = TextBox1.Text
    MW = TextBox2.Text
    PV = TextBox3.Text
    YP = TextBox4.Text

    vTable = New DataTable
    vTable.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    vTable.Columns.Add("Len", GetType(Double))
    vTable.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Double))
    vTable.Columns.Add("OD", GetType(Double))
    vTable.Columns.Add("Totlen", GetType(Double))
    vTable.Columns.Add("Vel", GetType(Double))

    id = DGV6.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value

    For i = 0 To DGV6.Rows.Count - 2
        vRow = vTable.NewRow
        vRow.Item(5) = (q / (2.448 * (id) ^ 2))
        For j = 0 To DGV6.Columns.Count - 1
            vRow.Item(j) = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString

        Next
        vTable.Rows.Add(vRow)
    Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

I have data in DGV6 and textbox, i like to do calculation on datatable item 5 each cell but after test, the result show only one calculated for entire columns not following each cell, any one can help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You only get the `id` value once from one row in the DataGridView.  You'll have to get it's value in each loop iteration:

```
For i = 0 To DGV6.Rows.Count - 2
    vRow = vTable.NewRow
    id = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    vRow.Item(5) = (q / (2.448 * (id) ^ 2))
    For j = 0 To DGV6.Columns.Count - 1
        vRow.Item(j) = DGV.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString

    Next
    vTable.Rows.Add(vRow)
Next
```

Comment: the table result still same as previously, i need calculating data from each row in colum id because the value was different